# help convert this SOAP request to Report Builder 2.0 query for XML data source

Tags: xml, soap, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder

I have a complex parameter to a web method in my .NET web service, and I want to query that web method with [Report Builder 2.0 using SOAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220468(v=SQL.100).aspx).  With [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/), I get the following SOAP request for that web method:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:qcr="MyNamespace">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <qcr:MyWebMethod>
         <qcr:MyComplexParameter><!--Represents a serializable class-->
            <qcr:Action>?</qcr:Action><!--string-->
            <qcr:ActionSortAscending>?</qcr:ActionSortAscending><!--Boolean-->
            <qcr:ActionSortOrder>?</qcr:ActionSortOrder><!--int-->
         </qcr:MyComplexParameter>
      </qcr:MyWebMethod>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The only kind of Report Builder 2 queries I've worked with before were for web methods that took strings, integers, or other simple types as parameters.  How would I go about writing a [Report Builder 2 query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207030(v=SQL.100).aspx) for this SOAP request?

Sample Report Builder 2 query for web method with simple parameters:

```
<Query>
   <Method Name="MyWebMethod" Namespace="MyNamespace">
   <Parameters>
       <Parameter Name="MyStringParameter"><DefaultValue>foo</DefaultValue></Parameter>
       <Parameter Name="MyNumericParameter"><DefaultValue>3</DefaultValue></Parameter>
   </Parameters>
   </Method>
   <ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">MyWebMethodResponse {}/MyWebMethodResult {}/Result</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I came up with was to change the web service's web method so it only takes simple parameters, then find some way of representing the complex object in a string and parsing that in the web method.  Key-value pairs and regex, JSON strings, etc.  This wouldn't work if I didn't have control over the web service's code, and it really seems like there ought to be a way of passing any kind of serializable parameter from Report Builder to an XML web service.  If I can pass a parameter in a normal SOAP request, I should be able to pass the parameter via Report Builder's stupid `Query` syntax.

If it helps anyone else, for parsing comma-separated key-value pairs of the format `key1=value1,key2=value2`, I used `new Regex(@"([^=,]*)=(""[^""]*""|[^,""]*)")` and `paramStr.Split(',').Select(pair => pair.Split('=')).ToDictionary(pair => pair[0], pair => pair[1])` to get an `IDictionary<string, string>` of parameters in my C# web service.

Comment: Did you ever find a better solution?