# XMLDP query with string array parameter - Report Builder

Tags: xml, soap, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder

I have an XML data source in a report, pointing at a C# web service of mine.  I don't know how to properly pass an array of strings as a parameter value in a query to that data source.

```
<Query>
   <Method Name="MyAwesomeMethod" Namespace="http://myawesomenamespace">
   <Parameters>
      <Parameter Name="regularParameter" Type="String">
         <DefaultValue>a normal string value</DefaultValue>
      </Parameter>
      <Parameter Name="fields">
         <DefaultValue><!-- what to put here? --></DefaultValue>
      </Parameter>
   </Parameters>
   </Method>
   <ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">*</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

In a regular SOAP request, I would have the following:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mynamespace="http://myawesomenamespace">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mynamespace:MyAwesomeMethod>
         <mynamespace:regularParameter>a normal string value</mynamespace:regularParameter>
         <mynamespace:fields>
            <mynamespace:string>value the first</mynamespace:string>
            <mynamespace:string>value the second</mynamespace:string>
         </mynamespace:fields>
      </mynamespace:MyAwesomeMethod>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My web service gives a sample SOAP 1.1 request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <MyAwesomeMethod xmlns="http://myawesomenamespace">
      <regularParameter>string</regularParameter>
      <fields>
        <string>string</string>
        <string>string</string>
      </fields>
    </MyAwesomeMethod>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So how would I pass an array of strings as the default value in an XMLDP query parameter?  This is related to [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321002/help-convert-this-soap-request-to-report-builder-2-0-query-for-xml-data-source), but not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays of simple types are represented the same way they serialize with an [XmlSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in .NET.

You can use the code below to see the serialization:

```
string[] example = new string[] {"One", "Two", "Three"};
string serializedExample = null;
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]));

using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, example);
    serializedExample = writer.ToString();
}

Console.WriteLine(serializedExample);
```

The code produces this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <string>One</string>
  <string>Two</string>
  <string>Three</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

When presenting this as a parameter, leave off the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>`. You can also omit `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` with no ill effects.

This should give you:

```
<Query>
   <Method Name="MyAwesomeMethod" Namespace="http://myawesomenamespace">
   <Parameters>
      <Parameter Name="regularParameter" Type="String">
         <DefaultValue>a normal string value</DefaultValue>
      </Parameter>
      <Parameter Name="fields" Type="Xml">
         <DefaultValue><ArrayOfString><string>One</string><string>Two</string><string>Three</string></ArrayOfString></DefaultValue>
      </Parameter>
   </Parameters>
   </Method>
   <ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">*</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

If that doesn't work, try removing the `ArrayOfString` tags. The important part is that your parameter type needs to be Xml.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround, since I control the web service code, is to change my web methods so they only take simple parameters, like `string fields` instead of `string[] fields`.  Then I use `new Regex(@"([0-9a-zA-Z]+)(,\s*[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*")` to ensure a comma-separated field list was passed and `fields.Split(',').Select(str => str.Trim()).ToArray()` to get a `string[]` like I wanted.

This works, but it seems silly because surely there exists some syntax, somewhere, that allows string arrays to be passed to an XML web service within Report Builder.  And of course this workaround wouldn't help at all if I couldn't change the web service.