# SSRS Report builder: how to create post soap array

Tags: reporting-services

I need to send payload like this to my server:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <enddate>2019-01-01</enddate>
   <field>9</field>
   <nodeparentid>0</nodeparentid>
   <startdate>2019-01-01</startdate>
   <triplets>
      <element>
         <element>0</element>
         <stratum>0</stratum>
         <well>195</well>
      </element>
      <element>
         <element>0</element>
         <stratum>0</stratum>
         <well>257</well>
      </element>
      <element>
         <element>0</element>
         <stratum>587</stratum>
         <well>189589</well>
      </element>
   </triplets>
   <ventureid>32</ventureid>
</root>
```

I found that I can do it this way in report builder:

```xml
<Query>
<Method Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Dynamics.Ax.Application" Name="GetInfo">
<Parameters>
<Parameter Name="enddate">
<DefaultValue>2019-01-01</DefaultValue>
</Parameter>
<Parameter Name="startdate">
<DefaultValue>2019-02-01</DefaultValue>
</Parameter>
<Parameter Name="field">
<DefaultValue>9</DefaultValue>
</Parameter>
<Parameter Name="nodeparentid">
<DefaultValue>32</DefaultValue>
</Parameter>
<Parameter Name="nodegrandparentid">
<DefaultValue>0</DefaultValue>
</Parameter>
</Parameters>
</Method>
</Query>
```

But I have no idea how to create an array of elements here. In my example, I need triplets array. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Answer can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15120138/8524139
or

```xml
<Query>
<Method Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Dynamics.Ax.Application" Name="GetInfo">
<Parameters>
<Parameter Name="enddate">
<DefaultValue>2019-01-01</DefaultValue>
</Parameter>
<Parameter Name="startdate">
<DefaultValue>2019-02-01</DefaultValue>
</Parameter>
<Parameter Name="field">
<DefaultValue>9</DefaultValue>
</Parameter>
<Parameter Name="nodeparentid">
<DefaultValue>32</DefaultValue>
</Parameter>
<Parameter Name="triplets" Type="Xml">
<DefaultValue>   
   <ArrayOfTriplets>
      <element>
         <element>0</element>
         <stratum>0</stratum>
         <well>195</well>
      </element>
      <element>
         <element>0</element>
         <stratum>0</stratum>
         <well>257</well>
      </element>
      <element>
         <element>0</element>
         <stratum>587</stratum>
         <well>189589</well>
      </element>
   </ArrayOfTriplets>
</DefaultValue>
</Parameter>
</Parameters>
</Method>
</Query>
```